# Shiboleth IDP is giving 503 when installed with default jetty server

Tags: jetty, shibboleth, idp

I have installed shiboleth IDP with default jetty container which comes along installation. The installation completed successfully. But when I try to access the IDP url (https://HOSTNAME/idp/profile/Status), it gives 503 error saying service not available.
I can see below in jetty logs:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shibboleth.DataSealerKeyStrategy' defined in file [C:\Program Files (x86)\Shibboleth\IdP\system\conf\global-system.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.component.ComponentInitializationException: Exception loading the default key
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 119 common frames omitted
Caused by: net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.component.ComponentInitializationException: Exception loading the default key
    at net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.security.BasicKeystoreKeyStrategy.doInitialize(BasicKeystoreKeyStrategy.java:249)
    at net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.component.AbstractInitializableComponent.initialize(AbstractInitializableComponent.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1760)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    ... 126 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.KeyException: java.io.IOException: Invalid secret key format
    at net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.security.BasicKeystoreKeyStrategy.getKey(BasicKeystoreKeyStrategy.java:329)
    at net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.security.BasicKeystoreKeyStrategy.updateDefaultKey(BasicKeystoreKeyStrategy.java:368)
    at net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.security.BasicKeystoreKeyStrategy.doInitialize(BasicKeystoreKeyStrategy.java:245)
    ... 134 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid secret key format
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineLoad(JceKeyStore.java:856)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.security.BasicKeystoreKeyStrategy.getKey(BasicKeystoreKeyStrategy.java:315)
    ... 136 common frames omitted
```

I tried to access the sealer.jks present in C:\Program Files (x86)\Shibboleth\IdP\credentials location but it gives error as  "incorrect keystore format".
Please suggest what am I missing.